# AWS API Gateway - How to create a post method and test it

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-api-gateway

My scenario is when my Lambda function's Api endpoint is hit, with a post variable, i want my Lambda to invoke a database connection and get some results.

So the first step is to create an API Gateway endpoint and I have problem creating the POST method with parameters

Here is what i did till now:

1. Created a API Endpoint for my Lambda Function.

[image]

[image]

2. When i go into the POST Method in Lambda's API endpoint section, i am taken to this screen

[image]

3. When i **Test** the function from the AWS Console,

[image]

and response is as follows in the console

[image]

How do i create parameters for the api here? and how do i test it? I have my **lambda function ready, that takes in a String as input and returns a String as response**.

Can someone guide me for the next steps..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check the [Create and Test a POST Method](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started.html#getting-started-new-post)

you do not mention the parameters in the lambda definition, the parameter will be taken from the request directly (so in future if you change your lambda code to take new parameters, you dont need to change the configuration

To test :

> In the Method Execution pane, in the Client box, and then choose TEST.
>
> Expand Request Body, and type the following:
>
> ```
> {
>   "name": "User" <or any other parameter that you expect>
> }
> ```
>
> Choose Test. If successful, Response Body will display the reply from
>   your lambda execution

For example here an example post api I had

[image]

so again for *POST* API you dont define the parameters

If you were doing *GET* API you would define the query parameters

[image]

Comment: if you have any example other than the documentation, can you please point to that? I read the documentation, but didn't quite understand the flow.

Comment: @VamsiChalla: Can you be specific about what you didn't understand in the documentation?

Answer (score 2):

Great step by step explanation of Serverless API on AWS: [Serverless API on AWS in 10 minutes](http://codeflex.co/serverless-api-on-aws-in-10-minutes/)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Frederic is very good, I'll just leave another example in the docs -> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html

Further down on that page is an example for Param Mapping which will proxy any incoming parameters to Lambda. You still need to explicitly state any incoming parameters that you expect clients to send in the Method Request.